# setPixels() behaving unexpectedly - Android Bitmap

Tags: android, android-bitmap

**EDIT :** I've included more of my actual code for clarity.

Consider this example code snippet

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etext = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                bmp=bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true);
                encode(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void encode(Bitmap bm)
    {
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int pixels[] = new int[height * width];
        bm.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        pixels[pixels.length - 1] = (byte) 1;
        pixels[pixels.length - 2] = (byte) 2;
        pixels[pixels.length - 3] = (byte) 3;
        bm.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

When I put output statements before `setPixels()`, I get correct values - the values that I want to store.

After `setPixels()`, in another part of the code I'm reading the same image. Over there when I read the values from indices I've modified, I get completely different values. The values I stored are overwritten.

1. I have tried both - typecasting to byte and not. At multiple places. Didn't solve my issue.
2. The values I'm storing at those indices are in the range 0-127, ASCII range. Well within the byte range.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Right now you only seem to be setting the last three pixels to a transparent-ish color.

Comment: @Nicolas I'm attempting to create a steganography app. In my actual code I select different indices, but for this example I just changed the last 3 values.

Comment: the question requires more information. Kindly attach the snippet of your activity which is using this piece of code

Comment: @sonofel You say you're setting values in the 0-127 range to the pixels, but these are all transparent. Colors are stored in 32-bit ARGB, so in this case the alpha value will always be 0.

Comment: @Android1005 I have edited the post

Comment: @Nicolas I don't exactly understand what you mean. I'm a newcomer to all this and some online examples I saw gave me the confidence that I could directly manipulate pixel values this way. I would greatly appreciate it if you elaborated on your answer.

Comment: Not really sure but you can look into this link once, if it might solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019825/android-setpixels-explanation-and-example

Comment: @sonofel You could use `Color.argb` to set the colors instead. Take a look at [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color) to understand how colors are encoded.